# Admob test ads not working, only the real ones are showing - Android

Tags: android, admob

I have implemented admob in my new game. Everything was fine, but accidentally for some reason test ads stops showing (real ads on real device works fine) with following message:

> `10-14 09:28:10.133: I/Ads(578): adRequestUrlHtml: <html><head><script
>   src="http://media.admob.com/sdk-core-v40.js"></script><script>AFMA_buildAdURL({"preqs":8,"session_id":"760111204008742348","u_sd":1,"seq_num":"9","slotname":"a15079ad976bb3e","u_w":1280,"msid":"com.jgrzesik.sokobangarden.android","simulator":1,"cap":"m,a","adtest":"on","js":"afma-sdk-a-v6.1.0","toar":0,"isu":"B3EEABB8EE11C2BE770B684D95219ECB","cipa":0,"format":"320x50_mb","net":"ed","app_name":"1.android.com.jgrzesik.sokobangarden.android","hl":"en","u_h":752,"carrier":"310260","ptime":788505,"u_audio":4});</script></head><body></body></html>`
>
> `10-14 09:28:11.875: I/Ads(578): Received ad url: <url:
>   "http://googleads.g.doubleclick.net:80/mads/gma?preqs=8&session_id=760111204008742348&u_sd=1&u_w=1280&msid=com.jgrzesik.sokobangarden.android&cap=m%2Ca&adtest=on&js=afma-sdk-a-v6.1.0&toar=0&isu=B3EEABB8EE11C2BE770B684D95219ECB&cipa=0&format=320x50_mb&net=ed&app_name=1.android.com.jgrzesik.sokobangarden.android&hl=en&u_h=752&carrier=310260&ptime=788505&u_audio=4&u_so=l&output=html&region=mobile_app&u_tz=0&client_sdk=1&ex=1&slotname=a14e8f77524dde8&askip=3&caps=inlineVideo_interactiveVideo_mraid1_th_autoplay_mediation_sdkAdmobApiForAds_di&jsv=38"
>   type: "admob" afmaNotifyDt: "null">`
>
> 10-14 09:28:12.162: I/Ads(578): onFailedToReceiveAd(Ad request
>   successful, but no ad returned due to lack of ad inventory.)

This seems very unusual because I use

> addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);

method in my ad request. To be sure I decided to check my apk file from yesterday (when test ads was 100% working) and I get the same message. I decided even to install an apk file from my one year old game onto emulator to check this, and I get the same results. 
I double check my app settings in admob panel and I use correct publisher id in my aps, and also "Use test mode setting set in client code" option is in power.
I will be very pleased if someone share his experience with dealing this kind of problems (or maybe someone can confirm that this is the problem on server-side).
I'm using admob 6.1.0 and 4.1.1 in my old project.
Thanks!

Comment: I experience same problem (since yesterday) with Admob test ads - setting request.testing = false give live ads and works as expected. No error in my code, been running Admob ads for about a year now (iOS), just upgraded to new SDK (have had test ads running with new SDK). I'm sure this problem is server-side and will be fixed soon...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue, as Mads said there was a problem on admob side but they have solved it. They just answered in the [support forum](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-admob-ads-sdk/bZMvQUrqIS4/Yv1HrigwASsJ) and I confirm it's working for me.